# How can i retrieve the API Limit Info in Salesforce?

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am retrieving my service and calling the following after a successful login

```
  SforceService myservice = null;
  LimitInfo apiLimits = null;

  if (myservice.LimitInfoHeaderValue != null)
            mylimits = myservice.LimitInfoHeaderValue.limitInfo[0];
```

but the myservice.LimitInfoHeaderValue is always null ?
I would assume it would get populated with the data on a successful login ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_limitinfo.htm `All calls, except for login().`

Comment: Yes its tagged on every Soap call, but i cant see an individual Soap call after login ?